# Windows 10 CPU Performance stucks at 46%

Tags: windows-10, cpu

Long story short, I've tried to load my CPU with [HeavyLoad](https://www.jam-software.com/heavyload/) (some of my programs work slow) and saw that it stucks at 46% (see screenshot):

[image]

Does it mean that my CPU doesn't work at full power? If so, how to break this 46% border?

I also attach a screenshot from OpenHardwareMonitor:
[image]

Comment: Is the CPU set to 100% in the powersettings?

Comment: Yes: High Performance, 100%. Both minimum and maximum processor state.

Answer (score 0):

Im just guessing, but I can see your graph is showing one bar.  This means it is showing the average of the CPUs two cores.  Since, the program should me maxing the CPU utilization at 100% and you are getting half that number, I strongly suspect the program you are using is only running on one core.  Just glancing at the HeavyLoad website, it does look like the software can be configured at a per-core level, so make sure it is set to use the entire CPU, not just one core.

Another things I just noticed is your clock speed.  Your CPU has a max of 2.6 GHz, but the graph is showing 1.2 GHz.  Something is slowing down the clock speed.  It could be software, hardware settings, or thermal throttling.  You need to investigate.

---

Ok.  Since you updated your screenshot, its definitely the CPU clock speed that is reducing your speed.  Something is slowing your CPU speed.  As mentioned, it could be software, hardware, or thermal throttling.  Disable programs like Intel SpeedStep, which can slow your computer down.  It can also be disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot. As I see, two cores are loaded. Also it should not be a thermal throttling since the temperature of my processor is ~50* C.